# php wkhtmltoimage listen for alert from url for screenshot

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

Im using wkhtmltoimage to take a screenshot of a page but my issue is that the page that loads for the screenshot sends out a alert with some details about croping that i need to listen for. Does anyone know how i can listen for the alert with wkhtmltoimage and get the details to use.

Iv done something similar with Cutycapt. Heres my command

```
 $cutyResult = shell_exec('export DISPLAY=:99 && /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage --width ' .$data['screenshots']['screenwidth']. ' --heigh ' .$data['screenshots']['screenheight']. ' ' . $url . ' /data/output.png && --expect-alert "screenshot" 2>&1 | grep crop')
 $cutyResult = trim($cutyResult);
 preg_match("/\[alert\] \"cropx=([0-9]+)&cropy=([0-9]+)&cropwidth=([0-9]+)&cropheight=([0-9]+)\"/", $cutyResult, $matches);
 print_r($matches);
```

But this doesnt seem to be waiting for the alert? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the alert best out a log from the web server.

For example, if you do a:

```
tail -f  /var/log/apache2/error.log

wkhtmltoimage: cannot connect to X server
or any error messages generated from the program.
```

Parse the error message with `tailf` and pipe `grep` the error that you're looking for.

Comment: What your saying can work but my problem is that i need to wait for the screenshot to happen also until this alert pops up because thats when i know the page is fully loaded and i dont want to use the delay functionality because its not reliable but +1 for the idea